# browser storage using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to create a form so when the user fills out the form, everything is stored into the browser storage.

However, I'm currently wonder how to get the values from the controls on the page and store them in session storage using the same key names as the response.html file..

The output I'm currently getting is undefined on every element.

```js
"use strict";
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

var saveReservation = function() {
    
    
    // submit form
    $("reservation_form").submit();
};

window.onload = function() {
    $("submit_request").onclick = saveReservation;
    $("arrival_date").focus();
};
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
fieldset {
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding: .5em;
}
legend {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 85%;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
label {
    float: left;
    width: 90px;
}
input, select {
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
input {
    width: 14em; 
}
input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 1em;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reservation request</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reservation.css">
    <script src="reservation.js"></script>
</head>
 
<body>
    <main>
 <h1>Reservation Request</h1>
 <form action="response.html" method="get"
     name="reservation_form" id="reservation_form">
            <fieldset>
         <legend>General Information</legend>
         <label for="arrival_date">Arrival date:</label>
         <input type="text" name="arrival_date" id="arrival_date"><br>
         <label for="nights">Nights:</label>
         <input type="text" name="nights" id="nights"><br>
         <label>Adults:</label>
         <select name="adults" id="adults">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>                              
         </select><br>
         <label>Children:</label>
         <select name="children" id="children">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>                              
         </select><br>         
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
         <legend>Preferences</legend>
         <label>Room type:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="room" id="standard" value="standard" checked>Standard          
  <input type="radio" name="room" id="business" value="business">Business
  <input type="radio" name="room" id="suite" value="suite">Suite<br>
                
         <label>Bed type:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="bed" id="king" value="king" checked>King
  <input type="radio" name="bed" id="double" value="double">Double Double<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="smoking" id="smoking" value="smoking">Smoking<br>
            </fieldset>  
            <fieldset>
      <legend>Contact Information</legend>
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
         <label for="email">Email:</label>
         <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
  <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
  <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"><br>
            </fieldset>

            <input type="button" id="submit_request" value="Submit Reservation"><br>
 </form>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--response-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reservation Request</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reservation.css">
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <script>
            document.write("<h3>The following reservation has been submitted</h3>");
            document.write("Name: ", sessionStorage.name, "<br>");
            document.write("Phone: ", sessionStorage.phone, "<br>");
            document.write("Email: ", sessionStorage.email, "<br>");
            document.write("Arrival Date: ", sessionStorage.arrivalDate, "<br>");
            document.write("Nights: ", sessionStorage.nights, "<br>");
            document.write("Adults: ", sessionStorage.adults, "<br>");
            document.write("Children: ", sessionStorage.children, "<br>");
            document.write("Room Type: ", sessionStorage.roomType, "<br>");
            document.write("Bed Type: ", sessionStorage.bedType, "<br>");
            document.write("Smoking: ", sessionStorage.smoking, "<br><br>");
        </script>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is `sessionStorage` set?

Comment: @guest271314 what do you mean?

Comment: Where do you initially set `sessionStorage` at `javascript`?

Comment: What you are doing doesn't seems like you are storing the data really. You can create a json and store it in session storage and then populate it back to response.html. But the way you have to do is formData->serializedJson->store. GetItem->DeserializeJson->display. If you are exactly willing to do, I can post the required code.

Comment: @Venky please do, I want to see the json version also

Answer (score 0):

The syntax seems wrong. Try these instead

To save data/initialize a sessionStorage:

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

To fetch a saved value from a sessionStorage

```
// Get saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.getItem('key');
```

Comment: Note, dot notation can get a set `sessionStorage` property.

Comment: this initializes session storage? @guest271314

Comment: @steven Yes. You need to set the items at `sessionStorage` if you expect to get items from `sessionStorage`.

Comment: `sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value')` is used to initialize a new one and `sessionStorage.getItem('key')` is used to fetch from that stored.

Comment: it still says undefined; do i need an if statement of some sort to repeat for each element?

Comment: when are you storing the values to your `sessionStorage` ?

Comment: get method to submit the data to the response.html page. Also, at the bottom of the form element, a button element (not a submit button) is used for the button that submits the form

Comment: just submitted the form would not work. How are you saving it to a `sessionStorage` variable in javascript ?? You must be saving it using this `sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value')` somewhere in javascript right ?

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge, what you are looking is to accept user data and display it in another HTML

You can do this by creating a JSON with form data and storing it in local storage. You can bring back that form and populate it to another page. You can use readonly attributes if you want to disallow editing. (Or simply make the fields display in a label/span/paragraph etc..)

The code goes like this:

***registration.html***

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <main>
    <h1>Reservation Request</h1>
    <form action="response.html" method="post"
        name="form" id="form">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>General Information</legend>
            <label for="arrival_date">Arrival date:</label>
            <input type="text" name="arrival_date" id="arrival_date"><br>
            <label for="nights">Nights:</label>
            <input type="text" name="nights" id="nights"><br>
            <label>Adults:</label>
            <select name="adults" id="adults">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>                                                
            </select><br>
            <label>Children:</label>
            <select name="children" id="children">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>                                                
            </select><br>           
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Preferences</legend>
            <label>Room type:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="room" id="standard" value="standard" checked>Standard             
        <input type="radio" name="room" id="business" value="business">Business
        <input type="radio" name="room" id="suite" value="suite">Suite<br>

            <label>Bed type:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="bed" id="king" value="king" checked>King
        <input type="radio" name="bed" id="double" value="double">Double Double<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="smoking" id="smoking" value="smoking">Smoking<br>
            </fieldset>     
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Contact Information</legend>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
        <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"><br>
            </fieldset>

            <input type="submit" value="SubmitReservation"><br>
    </form>
    </main>
</body>
```

**jQuery (3.1.1)**

You can use this in a script tag within your HTML

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var jsonObj = {};
    var jsonArr = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(jsonArr, function() {
        if (jsonObj[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!jsonObj[this.name].push) {
                jsonObj[this.name] = [jsonObj[this.name]];
            }
            jsonObj[this.name].push(this.value || "NA");
        } else {
            jsonObj[this.name] = this.value || "NA";
        }
    });
    return jsonObj; 
}
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {   
    console.log(jsonData); 
    var jsonData=$('form').serializeObject();
// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('jsonData', JSON.stringify(jsonData));
existingEntries.push(jsonData);
        return false;
    });
    });
```

***response.html***

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <main>
    <h1>Reservation Request</h1>
    <form action="response.html" method="post"
        name="form" id="form">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>General Information</legend>
            <label for="arrival_date">Arrival date:</label>
            <input type="text" name="arrival_date" id="arrival_date"><br>
            <label for="nights">Nights:</label>
            <input type="text" name="nights" id="nights"><br>
            <label>Adults:</label>
            <select name="adults" id="adults">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>                                                
            </select><br>
            <label>Children:</label>
            <select name="children" id="children">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>                                                
            </select><br>           
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Preferences</legend>
            <label>Room type:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="room" id="standard" value="standard" checked>Standard             
        <input type="radio" name="room" id="business" value="business">Business
        <input type="radio" name="room" id="suite" value="suite">Suite<br>

            <label>Bed type:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="bed" id="king" value="king" checked>King
        <input type="radio" name="bed" id="double" value="double">Double Double<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="smoking" id="smoking" value="smoking">Smoking<br>
            </fieldset>     
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Contact Information</legend>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
        <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"><br>
            </fieldset>

            <input type="submit" value="SubmitReservation"><br>
    </form>
    </main>
</body>
```

**jQuery (3.1.1)**

You can use this in a script tag within your HTML

```
$(function() {
var jsonString = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("jsonData"));
$.each(jsonString, function(key, value) {  
        var ctrl = $('[name='+key+']');  
        switch(ctrl.prop("type")) { 
            case "radio": case "checkbox":   
                ctrl.each(function() {
                    if($(this).prop('value') == value) $(this).prop("checked",value);
                });   
                break;  
                case "text":
                ctrl.val(value);

                break;
            default:
                ctrl.val(value); 
        }  
    }); 
});
```

***NOTE : CSS remains the same as yours for both files(reservation.css)***

You can have a look at the following jsFiddle to execute the above codes:

**[CLICK HERE FOR registration page](https://jsfiddle.net/5e4okgzt/1/)**

**[CLICK HERE FOR response page](https://jsfiddle.net/pfq8pdmn/)**

You can check out the local storage content in Google chrome by pressing
`F12 -> Application tab -> local storage on the left side navBar`